# ld fails to find glfw3

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, opengl, glfw

I'm trying to build [the OpenGL Super Bible 7th edition code samples](https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb7code) on Ubuntu 16.04. First I have to run cmake, which seems to work, and then I have to run make to compile.

I believe I have installed glfw3 and the Mesa OpenGL packages. When I execute cmake (after installing libglfw3 and libglfw3-dev), I get messages that OpenGL and GLFW3 have been found:

```
-- Found OpenGL: /usr/lib/libGL.so   
-- Checking for module 'glfw3'
--   Found glfw3, version 3.1.2
```

But when I execute make after cmake finishes, I get this error:

```
.../sb7code-master/src/sb7/sb7object.cpp: In member function ‘void sb7::object::render_sub_object(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)’:
.../sb7code-master/src/sb7/sb7object.cpp:212:77: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
                                          (void*)sub_object[object_index].first,
                                                                          ^
[  3%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sb7.dir/src/sb7/sb7shader.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sb7.dir/src/sb7/sb7textoverlay.cpp.o
[  4%] Building C object CMakeFiles/sb7.dir/src/sb7/gl3w.c.o
[  5%] Linking CXX static library lib/libsb7.a
[  5%] Built target sb7
Scanning dependencies of target wrapmodes
[  6%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/wrapmodes.dir/src/wrapmodes/wrapmodes.cpp.o
[  7%] Linking CXX executable ../bin/wrapmodes
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglfw3
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/wrapmodes.dir/build.make:95: recipe for target '../bin/wrapmodes' failed
make[2]: *** [../bin/wrapmodes] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:99: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/wrapmodes.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/wrapmodes.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

So I tried to see whether glfw3 was installed. I am a Linux newbie, so I found these commands online:

```
sudo  pkg-config --libs glfw3
```

That spits out:

```
-lglfw
```

Whereas when I enter `sudo pkg-config --libs glfw` without a 3 on the end I get:

```
Package glfw was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `glfw.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'glfw' found
```

And I tried: `sudo ldconfig -p | grep "glfw"`

That spits out:

```
libglfw.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglfw.so.3
```

In contrast, `sudo ldconfig -p | grep "glfw3"` returns nothing.

Is this cmake file I downloaded set up incorrectly to tell the linker `-lglfw3`, when it should be telling it `-lglfw`?  Or are my library paths somehow not correctly defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad/out-of-date `CMakeLists.txt`.

[Line 28 of `CMakeLists.txt`](https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb7code/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L28) is:

```
set(COMMON_LIBS sb7 glfw3 X11 Xrandr Xinerama Xi Xxf86vm Xcursor GL rt dl)
                        ^ wat
```

Should be:

```
set(COMMON_LIBS sb7 glfw X11 Xrandr Xinerama Xi Xxf86vm Xcursor GL rt dl)
                        ^ no 3
```

Better yet they should probably be using [`find_package()` to find GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build_guide.html#build_link_cmake_package).